# Microsoft Outlook is not syncing over LTE/4G network

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have Microsoft Office LTSC Professional Plus 2021, when I connect my laptop to ADSL network, Outlook works fine. However, when I connect it to 4G network it stops from syncing and the status become trying to connect.


Knowing that the internet speed is high and stable.


I tried to reinstall office, to delete outlook account, repair ost file, delete ost file, disable adds-on, run in safe mode, clear DNS cash and all of these solutions failed.


Windows and BIOS and Drives are up to date.


Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Probably no solution because there's absolutely NO reason for that happen other than active blocking it in the mobile data service. Ask your mobile data provider.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I tried something now, my 4G modem provider are the same as my mobile provider, when I connected to mobile data using hotspot the outlook become working but when I connected back to modem everything become working. I don't understand why maybe something related to ip but now the outlook is working.
Thank you my problem resolved.

Comment: @ChanganAuto that statement is false. See my answer.

Comment: @LPChip No, it isn't. It may have wrongly assumed someone who studied Management Information Systems and a member here for 8+ years would have checked such basic stuff already. +1 for your answer that didn't assume basic knowledge that isn't there at the end of the day.

Answer (score 2):

This is a default behavior. Whenever you use a network where usage fees are applied, Outlook will automatically put you in offline mode.

This is called a metered connection.

You should be seeing a notice somewhere with the option Connect anyway.

In Windows, you can go to Settings -> Network and Internet, click the connection, properties and you will find an option called Metered connection, that is enabled.

If you disable this, the connection is treated as a normal one. Other things like windows update will also download their things, so if you have a bandwidth limit, changing this is not a good idea, or you will indeed likely get billed for excessive usage (or the connection drops).

Comment: This is not the case, Metered connection was disabled and I didn't get any notice that my connection is metered. The issue was solved when I connected via mobile hotspot then I connected back to my 4G modem, knowing that my mobile carrier and 4G provider is the same. I don't know why but think issue related to ip configuration or something similar.

Comment: @m7mdabuodeh Your computer doesn't know where the WiFi comes from. Once it's connected to WiFi, it doesn't know that it is coming from a hotspot device or a router or some other service and device.

Comment: Like @music2myear says, with the exception of doing a VPN over mobile hotspot, then I found out windows may see it as a metered connection for some reason.